# Compiler optimization for return value?

Tags: c

I just made a simple function which returns the longer of the char*s entered and prints it to the console. I expected some form of segmentation fault once both char*s are equal yet it prints the second char* to the console every time. Is this a form of compiler optimization or am I missing something?

Sample input: `./longer test test` will output the second "test" (argv[2]).

Tried with both clang and gcc out of curiosity, same result.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char* longer(char *, char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%s", longer(argv[1], argv[2]));
    return 0;
}

char* longer(char* s1, char* s2) {
    char *first, *second;
    for(first = s1, second = s2; *s1 && *s2; s1++, s2++);
    return *s1 > *s2 ? first : second;
}
```

For clarification, the longer function is comparing the current position's ascii values, due to the loop breaking at the null byte. In essence the comparison would be 0 > 0, right?

Comment: The behavior you see is fine but your assumption is not correct. `0 > 0` is false so `second` is retured

Comment: Ahh, wow, I see the light, I don't know why I was mind blown for the past 20 minutes. Thank you, silly question.

Comment: `return *s1 ? second : first;` provides a simpler comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to return something. So it'll return based upon "true" or "false". If s1 is not greater than s2, it returns false. In this case it's the string 'second'.

Answer (score 0):

`0 > 0` is false. (It makes sense. zero is not greater than zero).

Since it's false the second string is returned, because that's what your ternary operator says to return whenever the condition is false.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional `return *s1 > *s2 ? first : second;` may also fail if your system uses signed char, and you input a string with characters beyond 0x7F.  Better and simpler is:

```
return *s1 ? first : second;
```

Comment: I was thinking of explicitly casting the char*s to unsigned upon comparison, but this is much more elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you need to sacrifice legibility for the reduction of branch conditions:

```
char* longer(char* first, char* second) {
    char *s1 = first, *s2 = second;
    for ( ; ; ++s1, ++s2 )
       if(!*s2)
           return first;
       if(!*s1)
           return second;
    }
}
```